# Vue Froala and Laravel Mix - Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/core-js/json/stringify'

Tags: vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix, froala

I'm trying to install Vue froala on my Laravel project.
I followed the exact instruction provided here: https://github.com/froala/vue-froala-wysiwyg but I get:

```
Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/core-js/json/stringify
```

Not sure if I have to touch the webpack.mix.js. I only try to add jQuery required by Froala. So now it looks like that:
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

```
mix.webpackConfig(webpack => {
    return {
            resolve: {
                extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
            alias: {
                '@':__dirname + '/resources'
            }
        },


       plugins: [

         // ...

         // Jquery loader plugin.
         new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           $: "jquery",
           jQuery: "jquery"
         })
       ]
    }
})
```

I found people fixing a similar problem manually installing *babel-runtime* as a package.json dependancy. I did, but it didn't work.

Any help?

Comment: Try using `dev-master` for now, looks like they've fixed but haven't released it yet.

Comment: Excuse me, what is that?

Comment: The version of the package that is installed. It's probably `2.9.3` in `package.json`, change that to `dev-master` and re-install your node modules. Does that fix it?

Comment: I reinstalled  vue-froala-wysiwyg using  npm install vue-froala-wysiwyg dev-master but it installed the same version (v2.9.3). And therefore, I still got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a [recommendation](https://github.com/froala/vue-froala-wysiwyg/issues/104), I used:

```
import VueFroala from 'vue-froala-wysiwyg/dist/vue-froala.min.js'
```

... which worked for me.